# Add new field to Solr schema and import only that perticular column

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene

I want to know if there is any way to update only one field in solr using import handler. Here are some steps I performed  :

1) I have defined a schema which contains some dynamic fields. 
2) I added some records to solr using data import handler from sql table.
3) A new column gets introduced in the sql table and entries for that column in sql table has been populated based on some existing columns (No new rows has been added).

Is there any way to index only this newly generated column without importing the whole data again?

Comment: Can you try this out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006045/can-solr-dih-do-atomic-updates) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [atomic update](http://yonik.com/solr/atomic-updates/). I dont know how to use the DIH to do atomic updates, but if you can form a document such that it adheres to the atomic updates format you can probably update the document. But, to apply atomic updates there are some [guidelines](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates) which are based on the architecture you have used for SOLR. The most important one according to me is that all the fields of the documents should be `stored`, else you will loose the `index` for the `unstored` fields.